# Flutter - How to scroll Container over another

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm begginning Flutter and I'm searching to scroll ListView over a Container like below

[image: scrollover]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DraggableScrollableSheet`

```dart
DraggableScrollableSheet(
  builder: (context, scrollController) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      controller: scrollController,
      child: Column(
        children: [],
      ),
    );
  },
)
```

You can follow the [doc example](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DraggableScrollableSheet-class.html)

A complete widget

```dart
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  openDraggable(context) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        isScrollControlled: true,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(22),
          topRight: Radius.circular(22),
        )),
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => DraggableScrollableSheet(
              maxChildSize: 1,
              initialChildSize: .4,
              expand: false,
              builder: (context, scrollController) {
                return SingleChildScrollView(
                  controller: scrollController,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
                        ListTile(
                          title: Text("item"),
                        ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
            ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                openDraggable(context);
              },
              child: Text("open"),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: But DraggableScrollableSheet didn't scroll to top, its fixed in bottom of app

Comment: You need to do some config like providing `maxChildSize: 1,` run the example code, you will get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `DraggableScrollableSheet`. instead of that widget use the `sliver` widget, this widget is amazing,
[you can use this article](https://www.raywenderlich.com/19539821-slivers-in-flutter-getting-started) and [this](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/advanced/slivers)

Comment: I have searched about Slivers but I want to have the header (blue part) fixed and the sheet scrolls over it.
After some tests, I think it isn't possible with Slivers (if you know how to have this behaviour, I'll take it!)

Answer (score 0):

```
CustomScrollView(
    slivers: <Widget>[
      // appbar of search page

      SliverAppBar(
  // icon in top left
  leading: _icon(context),
  // backgroun of appbar
  backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
  // style of app bar
  pinned: true,
  floating: true,
  snap: true,

  expandedHeight: 130,
  // obtional filter for product
  flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
    background: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 80.0),
      child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: borderRadius_30,
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight),
        child: TextField(
          
          onChanged: (value) {
            // you can sort data for user in this section
          },
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Theme.of(context).textSelectionColor,
          ),
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: InputBorder.none,

            // styel of labeltext in textfield

            labelStyle: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.cyan,
            ),
            labelText: Strings.search,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),

      // body 

      SliverList(
        delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
          (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return SearchBody(index);
          },
          childCount: fakeData.length,
        ),
        // number of object
      )
    ],
  ),
```

You can use the sliver package, something like this.